# db_connect takes very long to respond using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a strange issue that I have been seeing with the my web-app. I have running a Master-Slave (3) environment, using PHP and CodeIgniter. In order facilitate and Read / Write database group, I have set the `default` group to the be the master and the `replica` group to be the slave. By default, we use the master to do reads incase the information is time-sensitive and can't be affected by replication lag.

In order to load the `replica` class for use within my model - I've done the following:

```
class Api_methods_v4 extends Model {

public $clusterDB;
public $stats;

     function __construct() {
         parent::Model();

        if (is_resource($this->clusterDB)) {

        }
        else {
             $this->clusterDB = $this->load->database('replica', TRUE);
        }       
     }

    ....
```

}

Then in my code I am referring to `this->clusterDB->query($sql)` for the commands to refer to the `replica` instance instead of the `default` group.

The problem is that I use NewRelic to monitor my application, I can usually get very high PHP spikes through the application, which relate to this call:

[image: NewRelic Stack Trace]

This doesn't happen EVERY single time - but it happens enough to cause a concern. I tried to create a simple script that connects to the the `replica` db group 1000 times and measure the seconds it takes, and it was VERY fast - so I know that can't be the issue. Any one have any insights in this or is there a better way to tackle this?